# OPTIONS Preflight request executes POST's code - is that standard?

Tags: azure, cors, azure-functions, preflight

If I understand correctly, a preflight OPTIONS request is sent as a way of asking "what's allowed here?".  Then, once the response comes, if allowed, the calling site sends the POST request (or GET but in my case it's a post).  I have figured out that, at least with Azure Function Apps, the OPTIONS request is executing the code that I expected only the POST to execute.  I believe this to be the case because once I added some null checking (since the OPTIONS request doesn't have a payload in the body) everything worked fine.

I'm wondering if this is standard.

Seems to me that if I had written the API without using Azure Function Apps, I'd have the OPTIONS request sent down a path that would set the appropriate headers and return a 200 response.  And the POST request would be sent down a different path that would expect a payload in the body.  If that's how it usually works then that means I've just found an idiosyncrasy of the Azure functionality. But if not it means that I have something to learn about the OPTIONS preflight request.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Denise

Comment: It’s not standard. At least as far as what you seem to be describing. It’s not clear what you mean by *“the OPTIONS request is executing the code that I expected only the POST to execute”* — because the thing is, the browser fully controls the CORS preflight OPTIONS request, and the browser never sends any request body as part of that OPTIONS request. So there’s no request body for the server to process, and given that, then it’s unclear what the code you say is executing would be consuming. In other words, for the OPTIONS, the server just receives a request for a URL with a particular path.

Comment: Clarification posted as an answer due to the character limit here.  And thanks for the help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

As sideshowbarker mentioned, the OPTIONS request is sent automatically by the browser to check if the cross-origin request can be made.

In case of Azure Functions, this will handled by the Azure when running in the cloud.

If your function is being triggered, that would mean that you have `"options"` as a supported method for your [HTTP Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#trigger)

- In the HTTPTrigger attribute for C# functions
- In `functions.json` for non-C# functions

If you want to customize the CORS responses and/or running functions in a container, you could always include `"options"` as supported and respond differently when the incoming HTTP method is OPTIONS.

Also, if you are using [Azure API Management with Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition), you could offload CORS handling to it instead or even use [Functions Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) as shown [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1074#issuecomment-472699338).

Comment: Clarification posted as an answer due to the character limit here.  And thanks for the help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks y'all!  Sorry I was unclear.  And sorry it took me a while to get back.  Things have been a bit crazy on this end.

Yes, the function being called is mine.  And now I understand the browser doesn't have much choice as to whether or not it makes the OPTIONS call.

And yes, I could make my Azure function handle an options call differently and thanks for that suggestion too.  That's sort of what I ended up doing but basically I did it by handling an empty payload.  I didn't follow that best practice originally because I thought any valid request would have a payload.  Accordingly, any request that did not have a payload was invalid and should be turned away as a failure of some sort.  This was before I knew that the OPTIONS call was actually executing that function.

My remaining question is if I had NOT been using Azure... if I had rolled my own solution and hosted it somewhere, I'd have a class or at least methods that handle calls to this particular API.  (This is something I'm new to so bear with me if my terms aren't quite right and please do correct me).  So if I'd done my own API, I'd have one method to handle a POST call and a different method to handle an OPTIONS call, wouldn't I?  And the method that handles the OPTIONS call would return information about what's legally do-able with this API.  And the method that handles a POST call would handle the payload sent with it.  And the method that handles the POST wouldn't get executed when an OPTIONS request is sent.  At least that's how I figured it would work.  And that's my question -- is that how it's done when not letting something like Azure handle some of the infrastructure?

I'm just trying to learn if the OPTIONS request executing a POST's function is a standard practice or if it's some kind of idiosyncrasy to working with Azure functions.

Thanks again for the advice and for helping me understand these questions.